# ansible identify ssh user in ansible vars

Tags: ansible

In some ansible script I'm geting a

```
rsync: mkdir "/var/www/xxx" failed: Permission denied
```

I need to check what is the user my ansible is using in the target VM.

How can I print the user with a `debug:` line ?

I look for something like the `$ id` unix command to debug the permission Pb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible will always default to the current user(in the shell) and if you want to connect to a remote machine using a different user, you can use the **remote_user** in your ansible playbook.

See: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#remote-user for more details.

If you want to run a shell command and capture the output:

```
  - name: "Run a shell command"
    shell: /usr/bin/id
    register: result

  - name: Print the value of result
    debug: var=result
```

or

```
  - name: Print the user id using the ansible_user_id fact
    debug: msg="{{ansible_user_id}}"
```